# android COuntDownTimer stop and start new one

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

the program that i am making includes two different count down.

first, user has to type in the password within the time limit and press a button. If user can't input the password before the time limit, then it is over. However, if the user was able to input the password correctly before the time limit, a new timer should start.

```
    public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
{
    public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
    {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        if(hasPlanted == false) {
            text.setText("Time's up!");
            mTextView.setText("cya");
            btnEnable(false);
            startB.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
         text.setText(""+String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished))
                    ));
        }
}
```

this is the first timer, and it is working just fine. However, i am having trouble trying to stop this timer when user entered the correct password.

I have created another class of CountDownTimer, and when the user input the correct password within the time limit, the second timer starts. I put a boolean to stop the first timer to do anything when it ends, but I have no idea how I can fully stop that counter.

Comment: Add countdowntimer.cancel to start existing countdowntimer & create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create service and call that service in main class where timer is running and call the onReceive method

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Here you check the timer is running or not
              timer.cancel();
}
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  if(myTimer != null) { 
         myTimer.cancel();
         myTimer = null;
     }
```

This is in order to cancel the timer early. First check if it is null, and if it isn't, apply the cancel method on it. Let me know if this was helpful.

:)